# Returning header content - API Gateway + AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am developing a POST lambda function. I want to return "Location" in the header. So I configure API Gateway, like below:

[image: API Gateway configuration]

when I call the API, I am receving the "Location" correct in the header, but I am still receiving it on return message. Look below:

[[image: Returning Location[2]]

My python code:

```
def os_create_subscription (event, context):
    customer_id = event["customer-id"]
    subscription_id = 12345
    header_location = ("/customers/%s/subscriptions/%d" % (customer_id, subscription_id))
    result = {"Location": header_location}
    return result
```

So i would like to have the Location just in the header. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Header mapping from response bodies was a recently added to API Gateway. You can see examples in our [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html).

Your mapping should be: `integration.response.body.Location`

***Edit:*** Apologies for misreading. To remove the Location from the response body, you would need to have a mapping template with an empty JSON body.

Comment: @PedroMagalhaes I realized I misread after posting. Please see edit.

Comment: Thanks guy. I will try it!